# How to get table/view name (i.e. remove schema prefix)

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

Given one of the following strings (which represent a table/view name in SQL Server):

```
var x = "[my-Table.request]"; 
var x = "[dbo].[my-Table.request]";
var x = "dbo.[my-Table.request]";
```

I would like to get the table name (by C# code): **my-Table.request**

Any ideas?
have i missed any possible representations here?

Comment: Semantically, the table name of `my-Table.request`, `dbo.my-Table.request` and `[dbo].my-Table.request` is: `request` (`my-Table` is the schema-name)

Comment: Your first, third and fifth examples are **not** a valid way to specify a table named `my-Table.request` for use in SQL. You *have* to quote the name (by `[]` or `""`) if it includes periods (`.`).

Comment: After edit down to four examples, example one still doesn't represent a valid way to specify the table named `my-Table.request`.

Comment: As I alluded to in my first comment, `"` may be used in place of `[` and `]` to achieve the same quoting effect. (So it'd be something like `"\"my-table.request\"";` in your C# code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply via `PARSENAME` in TSQL:

```
PARSENAME(@x, 1)
```

With your edit where you want it in C#, you'd basically have to write it from scratch in C#, tokenizing by the `.`, `[`, `]`. AFAIK there is no pre-canned implementation that does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this on the SQL side, there's a [`PARSENAME`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function for doing exactly that.

E.g. `PARSENAME(x,1)` returns the object (in this case table) name. `PARSENAME(x,2)` returns the schema, etc.

Answer (score -3):

you can use the below query:

USE MyDB
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO

**Please Note:**
MyDB is your database name